# ReactJS getting minified error even though I am using the non-minified files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJS for a project, and am trying to use the ReactCSSTransitionGroup addon (yes, I am loading the react-with-addons.js file). Here is the basics of what I am doing in the render method:

```
var menu = this.state.menu ? <p>Here is the menu</p> : null;
return (
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionAppear={true}
        transitionAppearTimeout={100}
        transitionEnterTimeout={100}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={100}
        transitionName="fade">
            {menu}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
);
```

Here is my SCSS file:

```
.fade-enter, .fade-appear {
  opacity: 0;

  &.fade-enter-active, &.fade-appear-active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out;
      transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out;
  }
}

.fade-leave {
  opacity: 1;

  &.fade-leave-active {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out;
      transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

The menu will show up the first time I call `this.setState({ menu: true });` (though it doesn't fade in, it just shows up) but after that even when I call `this.setState({ menu: false });` it doesn't go away.

The frustrating part is that I am getting an error the first time I change the `menu` state, but it is giving me a minified error even though I have the development versions of both `react-with-addons.js` and `react-dom.js`

```
Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev
environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.
```

I am sure if I got a full error message I could figure out what I am doing wrong, but it is giving me the generic error message an I don't know why.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

I was using gulp for a while, but switched to using webpack, and even though I was including react in webpack I was still loading the external files. This ended up being what was causing issues, because there were two versions of react loaded, so I just had to attach a handle to React to the window so I could access it from my other javascript file, and everything is working now.